# Error: Declaration is incomparable with 'function name'

Tags: c++, function, object

What I'm trying to do is pass an object (class) into a function constructor. The code essentially looks like this:

```
class Primary{
    Primary(void);
      ~Primary(void);
};
//champion.h
//looks like
public:
Champion(void);
Champion::Champion(char name1[], int stringLength, int type1, double health1, int fluid1, double armor1, double specialA1, double damage);
char* getName(void);
double getHealth(void);
int getFluid(void);
double getArmor(void);
double getSpecialA(void);
double getDamage(void);
int type;
void setHealth(double health);
void setFluid(int fluid);
void setArmor(double armor);
void setSpecialA(double specialA);
void setDamage(double physDamage);
void setPrimary(Primary prime1);


//champion is another class
void Champion::setPrimary(Primary prime1)
{
   prime = prime1
}
```

Most of my code is here http://codepad.org/PMHZNtF9

I get an error that says

> Error: Declaration is incomparable
>   with 'void
>   Champion::setPrimary(
>   prime)" (declared in champion.h)"

I'm not sure what this means but I know it's possible to pass an object of a class into a function via parameter. What am I doing wrong? to be a little bit more clear I would like to know what the error means. and as far as I know everything declared as is. take a look and give me some ideas as to what might be the problem and hopefully I have not one small typo!

Comment: Can you show us the declaration of the method?

Comment: Maybe you should check how the setPrimary() is declared in the champion.h.

Comment: Speaking about typo, your title was incorrect for the past 6 years. Also, please do not fully externalize your code, otherwise your question becomes off-topic for StackOverflow as looking _incomplete_.

Answer (score 0):

Dumb question, but are these all in one file? If not, does champion.cpp (or whatever it's called) have a reference to the `Primary` class, via `#include "primary.h"`?

EDIT:

Okay, what you've shown so far compiles if I do a quick reconstruction. One immediate thing I see is in the last chunk of code you have there:

```
void Champion::setPrimary(Primary prime1)
{
   prime = prime1
}
```

Where is **prime** defined? The only field I see right now is type, which is an int.

Comment: they are in separate files and yes i do have a reference to Primary class via #include "Primary.h"

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in the source code that you have shown here which will give the error you mentioned. So probably, you missed out something while copy pasting the code here. The error suggests that there is mis-match in the declaration for function `Champion::setPrimary` Probably yo should check if its declaration exactly matches the definition in your code or else If you can use [codepad](http://codepad.org) and post a sample of your code which actually gives a error, We can help you better.

There are a few points to note in the code above:

1. `prime` being used inside the `Champion::setPrimary` is not declared inside the `class Champion`. Probably since you copy pasted the code maybe that section got left out.
2. `class Primary` declares its constructor as `Private`, From the code pasted here it not sure that is intentional(don't see you using `Singleton`) or just amistake.